# No option to upload site logo on wordpress site logo block not even replace option

Tags: css, wordpress, twenty-twenty-three-theme

I am trying to customize the twenty twenty three theme with full site editor all thing works fine but the site logo block just insert a rectangular box except any link to upload the logo even no option available to replace the logo as the following picture. I am new in wordpress & can not resolve the problem.

I have only custom css plugin installed & I tried deactivating the plugins but in vain.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling LiteSpeed Cache plugin.